# Are the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix continuous as function of the elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory

Let $A_\theta =((a^\theta_{i,j}))_{d\times d}$ be a real-symmetric matrix indexed by a vector $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Is $\theta \mapsto \lambda_{\max}(A_\theta)$, the maximum eigenvalue of $A_\theta$, a differentiable function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is continuous, but not differentiable.

To see that it is not differentiable, consider a situation in which
$$
A_{\theta(t)} = \pmatrix{t&0\\0&-t}
$$
Then we have $\lambda_{max}(\theta(t)) = |t|$, which is not differentiable.

Comment: However, I think there's a theorem which states that it is *possible* to smoothly select an eigenvalue.  In this case, something like $\lambda_1(A_{\theta(t)}) = t$ would work.  Finding such a selection is, however, non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks! is it Lipschitz? That is $|\lambda_{max}(A_\theta)-\lambda_{max}(A_{\theta_0})| \le L |\theta-\theta_0|.$?

Comment: Yes.  In particular, $|\lambda_{\max}(A_\theta) - \lambda_{\max}(A_{\theta_0})| \leq C\|A_{\theta} - A_{\theta_0}\|$.  I believe a result to this effect exists in Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis*.

Comment: Thanks! What would be the required conditions on $a_{i,j}^\theta$?

Comment: The inequality I wrote holds in all cases.  This only becomes your Lipschitz inequality if the $a_{i,j}^\theta$ are themselves Lipschitz functions of $\theta$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is this for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33256/discussion-between-rohit-and-omnomnomnom).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, do you have a reference for the theorem that it's possible to smoothly select an eigenvalue?

Comment: @Monty123 not off the top of my head.  I would guess that Bhatia's Matrix Analysis says something about it, but I'm not 100% on that.  Horn and Johnson's Topics in matrix analysis would be a second guess